# Within a ListView, why do I keep getting the value of the first row instead of the selected row?

Tags: android

In my android app I have the following code:

```
public void goToCaptureBonus (View View) {
        String tappedBonus = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.bonusListCode)).getText().toString();
        Log.e(TAG,"goToCaptureBonus, tapped bonus = " + tappedBonus);
        Intent goToCaptureBonus = new Intent(this,captureBonus.class);
        goToCaptureBonus.putExtra("codeTapped",tappedBonus);
        startActivity(goToCaptureBonus);
    }
```

Whenever I tap on a row, the log always shows the first row (AK1 in this case). I get that ListView is making one row, and repeating it; but the values of each row do display correctly. Why does the above code always return the first row, rather than the value from the row that was tapped?

Comment: You should use `setOnItemClickListener` in `ListView`.

Comment: I tried that using the following: `listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.e(TAG,"Entered onItemClickListener");
                Toast.makeText(bonusListing.this, "You clicked "+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //Intent nextActivity = new Intent(bonusListing.this, bonusListing.class);
                //startActivity(nextActivity);
            }
        });` but that doesn't work.

Comment: what is the `position` value ?

Comment: @JohnJoe I suspect the `setOnItemClickListener` isn't working because I'm using a `FrameLayout` that takes up the whole row, so technically the button is intercepting the tap, not the row itself.

Comment: Can you show more code ?

Comment: @JohnJoe I'm not sure what you mean by the `position` value...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191883/discussion-between-djfriar-and-john-joe).

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation of `findViewById()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewById(int)) says

> Finds the first descendant view with the given ID, ...

Is it possible that you are using `findViewById()` from the context of the activity or the the general list view and not of the selected (tapped on) view?

If the `view` parameter of your function is the tapped on view, you should probably do:

```
view.findViewById(R.id.bonusListCode)
```

instead of just

```
findViewById(R.id.bonusListCode)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case of ListView you should use `OnItemClickListener`. Here is an example how to do this.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //use the position variable to get the list item from the list
        String selection = itemsArray[position]; // this will give the selected item 
    }
});
```

Now whenever an item on your ListView is tapped, the method `onItemClick()` is called. And here you can get the selection.