# When using onItemClickListener why is the wrong row is being returned?

Tags: android

In my app I have the following code:

```
// Populate the ListView w/ all rows
        Cursor data = appDBHelper.getAppDataAllBonuses();
        listView.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.bonus_list_row_item, data,
                new String[] {"sCode", "sName", "sCategory", "sCity", "sState"},
                new int[] {R.id.bonusListCode, R.id.bonusListName, R.id.bonusListCategory, R.id.bonusListCity, R.id.bonusListState}, 0));

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //use the position variable to get the list item from the list
            String tappedBonus = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.bonusListCode)).getText().toString();
            Log.e(TAG,"goToCaptureBonus, tapped bonus = " + tappedBonus);
            Intent goToCaptureBonus = new Intent(bonusListing.this,captureBonus.class);
            goToCaptureBonus.putExtra("codeTapped",tappedBonus);
            startActivity(goToCaptureBonus);
        }
    });
```

When I run my app, and tap on a row, the value I'm getting for the bonusListCode is whatever the topmost row is. I assume my issue is that I'm not properly using the position to find the right view, but I'm not sure how to edit my code to make it do so.

How do I properly use the position to grab the value of the view inside the row that was actually tapped on?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55700888) on the most recent version of this question explains why that's happening, and gives the correct way to use `findViewById()` there. However, it would be preferable to use `position` to get the corresponding item from the dataset backing the `ListView`'s `Adapter`, and get the value from that, which is basically what [the other answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55702421) is saying.

Comment: @MikeM. I swear I've read that answer 4 million times, and it seriously just now made sense and fixed my issue. Thank you.

Comment: Just FYI, there are a few other ways to do that, but they all basically do the same thing, only through different methods on the `ListView` and `Adapter`. With your given setup, I suggested what I consider the most appropriate, but I've added links to the duplicates list that show examples of the other methods, if you're interested.